# How to find ranges of value from uniform prior distribution in r?

Tags: r

I coded a sequence and uniform prior distribution plot below, now according to the uniform prior distribution, How can I find the values of P (0.01 ≤ β ≤ 0.1) and P(0.1 ≤ β ≤ 1)? Thanks!

```
beta= seq(0.01,100,0.001)
beta
prior = rep(1/length(beta), length(beta)) 
#assigning equal prior probabilities to each possibility.
plot(beta,prior,
     type="h",
     main="Uniform Prior Distribution")
```

Comment: Since P is uniform, isn't the answere just 0.09 and 0.9? I do not see what you really try to achieve with R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are seeking for the cumulative probability.

```
find_prob <- function(data,prob,start,end) {

    sum(prob[which(data<= end & data>=start)])

}

find_prob(beta,prior,0.01,0.1)

0.0009100819

find_prob(beta,prior,5,100)

0.9500955
```